# can i have a scrollView which has many relativeLayouts

Tags: android, scrollview

I am writing an activity which has a linearLayout on the top and in the second half has a scrollView. The scrollView can get as many as 30 relativeLayouts at runtime. Is this possible?
I have tried with the following code but it gives an error:

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(hasFocus==false){
    switch(v.getId()){

    case 6:

        main[no]=new RelativeLayout(this);
        mainParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        main[no].setLayoutParams(mainParams);
        mainLayout.addView(main[no]);
        svParams=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        sv.setLayoutParams(svParams);

        items[no]=new EditText(this);
        rates[no]=new EditText(this);
        quants[no]=new EditText(this);

        items[no].setHint("Enter item name");
        rates[no].setHint("Rate");
        quants[no].setHint("Quantity");

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams etParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rateParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams quantParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        items[no].setId(id++);
        quantParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (id-1));
        quants[no].setId(id++);
        pos=id;
        rateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (id-1));
        rates[no].setId(id++);          

        etParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        items[no].setLayoutParams(etParams);
        rates[no].setLayoutParams(rateParams);
        quants[no].setLayoutParams(quantParams);

        rates[no].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        quants[no].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        main[no].addView(items[no]);
        main[no].addView(rates[no]);
        main[no].addView(quants[no]);
        quants[no].setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        sv.addView(main[no]);
        no++;
        break;
```

Each relative layout contains 3 editTexts adjacent to each other.

Comment: Any reason for not using a ListView?

Comment: can i use listView to place the editTexts in the same manner that i am doing now

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?

Comment: nullPointerException @ sv.addView(main[no]);

Answer (score 6):

ScrollView can have one child only. Add LinearLayout, which would contain all your RelativeLayouts and add LinearLayout to ScrollView

```
 <ScrollView ...

     <LinearLayout ...

         <RelativeLayout1 ... />

         <RelativeLayout2 ... />

      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

But the easiest way is to use ListView widget, which would re-use your views

Comment: As in the code, i am trying to add EditTexts dynamically. so even if i do it like you say, will it work. Like, for example if the user decides to enter more data then as he approaches the end of the screen, will the EditText automatically move in the scrollView

Comment: @kayveesin if and when you will use ListView, you would need a custom adapter to fill your ListView widget. This custom adapter would require you to override getView method, where you would be able to manage every view that would be displayed by the ListView and there you will be able to dynamically add your EditTexts

Comment: can i use a tableLayout?? Which one would be easy to program with minimum load on the resources at runtime

Comment: @kayveesin the minimum load on your program (resources do not experience any load) would be if you use ListView. I do not know the difference between the load on the application in case if you use RelativeLayouts or TableLayout, but i assume it is going to be the same. ListView creates a couple of rows to fill up the screen and while you scroll ListView, it creates automatically views reusing (filling new data on the old ones) old ones

Comment: @kayveesin but if you are sure that you will not have much data to display, then you can use ScrollView with Relativelayouts or TableLayout or anything else. It is all up to you. Try and see if your application will become slow if you use TableLayout

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add that many views in a layout, i would suggest using a ListView because the adapter will handle scrolling and reusing views as it is not so memory efficient to have 30 layouts with 3 editexts in a layout.

But if you want to use a scrollView.

ScrollView can have only one direct child.
So you can have something like this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!--Add your layouts here Like this -->
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: well you can pass in the listView Adapter whatever layout you want to use but it may be a little difficult to handle the values which have been inserted to the EditTexts for 30 rows :/

Answer (score 0):

For this U use Layout Inflater Like

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout_id">

    </LinearLayout >

    </ScrollView>
```

as main view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/layout_item_id">

    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, this is the inflated text :D"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/text_item_id"/>
   <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, this is the inflated text :D"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/text_item_id"/>
  <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, this is the inflated text :D"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/text_item_id"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is ur Relative layout with three text save it as layout_item.xml

and finally in mainlayout

u use after that switch case

```
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
//Here u can use for loop or something else to repleat the layout
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item, mainLayout,false);


            mainLayout.addView(view);
```

Thats it !!!!!